# OpenCV in Visual Studio crashes after running once

Tags: c++, opencv

I installed OpenCV for my Windows and integrated it into Visual Studio. I was following a video tutorial, which gave some test code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main() 
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 3);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;


    for (;;) 
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        imshow("Webcam frame", frame);

        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After restarting my computer it worked, but only once.
I tried recompiling it and got the following Errors

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\popp\Downloads\Open CV\opencv-master\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (912) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638

OpenCV(4.5.0-dev) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file C:\Users\popp\Downloads\Open CV\opencv-master\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 376
```

I really don't understand why it only works once and just after restarting. Anyone got an Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should do some error checking to ensure there is data in the frame before trying to display it

```
for (;;) 
{
    Mat frame;
    bool result = cap.read(frame);
    if(result && !frame.empty())
       imshow("Webcam frame", frame);

    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
        break;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and my console just keeps posting the first warning "can't grab frame"

Comment: I did, it didn't do anything